# Force browser to use ACTIVE FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, web, ftp

I have to download a file from a FTP Server via browser, but the ports on my PASV Data Channel are being blocked by the Firewall.

Is there any way I can force the browser to use ACTIVE FTP?

I have ports 20 and 21 available. I opened my DATAPORTS on [6000-7000] on my IIS Server, but my Firewall wont let anything throu, I have NO Access to the firewall.

Currently, I am just using `<a href="ftp://....>File</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can force the browser to use ACTIVE FTP?

Unfortunately no - it can't be forced if a firewall in the chain blocks it as you need to be able to accept incoming TCP connections. If your firewalls blocks these then there is no help to get.

> FTP may run in active or passive mode [...] In active mode, the client
>   creates a TCP control connection to the server and sends the server
>   the client's IP address and an arbitrary client port number, and then
>   waits until the server initiates the data connection over TCP to that
>   client IP address and client port number. **In situations where the
>   client is behind a firewall and unable to accept incoming TCP
>   connections**, passive mode may be used.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Communication_and_data_transfer